# TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file. Не создается PDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

использую библиотеку TCPDF для создания pdf, При выводе выдает ошибку: "TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file". Прочитал все статьи про эту ошибку делал следующее: ставил ob_end_clean(); перед output - не помогает. Открыл файл pdf в notepad там до PDF-1.7
вся страница html, удалил руками этот апендикс, страница открывается. Как она туда попадает? И как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 0):

Если кому пригодиться, нашел решение такое, перед созданием PDF вставил ob_end_clean();
не перед output а перед $pdf = new PDF();